# Load a SWF and have the loaded SWF load text dynamically (at runtime)

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

Not sure if what I am trying to do is possible.
I need to load a swf and have the loaded swf itself load a json file at  runtime.

As an alternative is there some way I might 'inject' the loaded swf with the json AFTER it has loaded??

This is the complete code for the loaded swf and the json file. it simply loads a JSON file and uses that to populate a textField. It works fine standalone ...

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import com.greensock.*;
    public class DynamicTextSWF extends MovieClip
    {

        public var marquee : MovieClip;
        private var _loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        private var _request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();

        public function DynamicTextSWF()
        {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
        }

        private function onAdded(e:Event):void {

            _request.contentType = "application/json";
            _request.url="config.json";
            _loader.load(_request);

            _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadConfirm);
            _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,decodeJSON);
            TweenLite.to(marquee,12,{x:stage.stageWidth,delay:2 });

        }


        private function loadConfirm(e:Event):void {
            trace("Load Successful" + "\n");
        }

        private function decodeJSON(event:Event):void {
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
            trace(loader.data.toString() + "\n");
            var result:Object = JSON.parse(loader.data);

            trace('result..content.description ='+result.content.description);

            marquee.info.text = result.content.description;
        }

    }
}
```

This is the json file

```
{
    "name": "ticker0",
    "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "description": "This is ticker text that is loaded dynamically",
        "required": true
    },
    "tween": {
        "type": "x",
        "duration": 4,
        "delay": 2
    },
    "style": {
        "font": "Futura",
        "color": "blue",
        "size": 12
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are all 3 files located? How/Where are you executing these files? Is this a security/sandbox problem? What exactly happens in when loading the json file from within the other container swf? Where do you listen for Error Events?

Comment: Before I go any further is what I am trying to do even possible? Is it simply a security sandbox issue and if so do I need to simply change the logic that loads the json? Or is this entirely controlled by the loading asset?

Comment: I think this should be possible. I guess this could be a sandbox issue, hence my question where things are located. What happens if you try to load the json directly from the "parent" swf? (that which loads the other one)

Comment: of course the parent swf can load the json directly.  I think an alternative to try would be to load the swf with a query string attached ie fo.swf?these%20are%20some%20vars%20to%20load will try and report back

Comment: I suggest you add listeners for errors etc. to the loader to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load any number of SWFs into each other, and then other assets into them, so I think you need to work out at what point your DynamicTextSWF class is failing when loaded into another SWF.

Assuming you have a way to see the trace statements, I would put more trace statements in - one in the DynamicTextSWF constructor, and one in its onAdded method and see how far it gets - is the DynamicTextSWF instance ever added to the stage?. I would also, as been suggested, add a listener for the IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR with another trace statement.

I use a tool called Vizzy which allows me to view the trace output for Flash debug content when playing in a browser in a Flash Debug Player. This also lets you view the Flash Player policy log, which shows you where there has been a security error.

I also use a tool called Charles which allows you to view network requests (a bit like the network panel in Chrome DevTools, but it does lots more useful things) - this allows you to see if there have been any 404 requests, in the case that your SWF is asking for the JSON data at the wrong URL.